# om2m issue... Unable to start the om2m platform

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, onem2m

**I AM USING RASPBERRY PI 3.**

I started IN-cse using `sudo su start.sh` command, I see following error & when I check  *http://127.0.0.1:8080/webpage* It won't start I see localhost not found error.

ONE M2M issue.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller (file:/home/pi/org.eclipse.om2m/org.eclipse.om2m.site.in-cse/target/products/in-cse/macosx/cocoa/x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Could you provide some more details? What implementation are you using? It looks like Eclipse om2m. What Java version and OS?

Comment: I am using java version 13

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the versions of your om2m and your Java installations are to far apart. A solution could be that you either compile your om2m installation with your new version of Java (including the Eclipse components), or that you use an older version of the Java runtime.

See, for example, the following discussions on the Eclipse forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089552/ or https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1098927/